# Textvariable not working with Entry (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble with the Entry widget from Tkinter in Python 3.4.1

When running this code, the Entry appears blank while I expect it to initially display "Var" :

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from tkinter import *

W = Tk()
V = StringVar() 
V.set("Var")
E = Entry(W, textvariable = V)
E.pack()

W.mainloop()
```

Comment: i see "var" in the Entry widget when i run your code, using pytohn 3.4?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.4.1

Comment: I ran it using 3.4.3, anyways, should work...

Comment: Just tried the code on my laptop, it indeed works fine with the same setup (python 3.4.1 + pyzo). I don't get why it doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: i don't know either =P

Comment: Just noticed I get a note in the shell when running : "Note: The GUI event loop is already running in the pyzo kernel. Be aware
that the function to enter the main loop does not block." I don't know what it means or if it's relevant though.

Comment: I set gui to "No GUI support" in Shell configurations, the note is no longer displayed and my code now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

W = Tk()
V = StringVar()
E = Entry(W, textvariable = V)
E.pack()
E.insert(0, "Var")

W.mainloop()
```